# Auto increment to new SNAPSHOT versions by maven

Tags: maven

I'm in need of a plugin that does the auto update of the SNAPSHOT version of the components that are released. `mvn release` doesn't seem to have similar functionality.

Comment: Does `mvn -U` not do what you want?

Comment: No. It checks for the latest versions of the current version SNAPSHOT. doesn't update the versions in the POM files, if the versions are moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the maven versions plugin will do what you are looking for: http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-next-snapshots-mojo.html

Comment: the link seems to be broken